# Luden's Echo and Karthus ult

Tags: league-of-legends

> Gains charges upon moving or casting. At 100 charges, the next spell hit expends all charges to deal 100 (+0.15 ability power) bonus magic damage to up to 4 targets on hit. Applies spell Effects (e.g., Spell Vamp, Rylai's, etc).

**How does this behave with Karthus ultimate?**

Comment: Luden's echo is simpley awesome :D

Comment: I used it on vlad yesterday and I went ham :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a Reddit post explaining the behavior between Luden's Echo and Karthus Ult:

- Luden's Echo cannot bounce more than once.
- Luden's Echo prioritises the first pick (press tab it's the first champion on red team)
- Luden's Echo hits invisible targets
- Luden's Echo when hitting minions also hits invisible targets.
- Luden's Echo does not proc on Karthus E or W.
- Karthus E does not add "20" to the Luden's Echo Counter.

This is the TL;DR, did not want to post the entire article here. If you want to give it a read, you can check it out here: http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/2yskwz/ludens_echo_karthus_interaction/

Comment: Luden's Echo does proc on Defile, used it a few times to test it. At the very least, it procs on its activation but I'm sure I saw it proc after too. That said, I don't feel I'll keep that item in my normal Karth's build, doesn't add enough damage to be worth it on Karth

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I think Karth has great wave clear and Luden's Echo is mostly used for mages with low wave clear. I agree with you, I do not recommend building this item on Karth.

Comment: The money needed for it and what it brings as wave clearing power is not enough to justify the gold IMO. It won't one shot a range minion, it barely puts it at half health (iirc).